# Para que serve a reunião diária na metodologia SCRUM?

Tags: metodologia-ágil

Ao meu olhar superficial em relação a metodologias ageis e baseada em livros de administração, uma reunião recorrente ou fixa seguido de intervalos curtos são inúteis. A questão é:
 O que diferencia a reunião diária do **SCRUM** das demais reuniões existentes em uma empresa/negócio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quando comecei a estudar a metodologia SCRUM e vi que tinha uma tal de reunião diária algumas perguntas do seguinte tipo surgiram na minha cabeça:
- Essa reunião não é perda de tempo?
- Que diabo de assunto terá para discutir todo dia?

Então fui pesquisar um pouco mais sobre do que realmente é tratada a reunião diária do SCRUM em diversos blogues e qual a sua devida importância. Inclusive os seguintes blogues me ajudaram a escrever esse post:

http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/scrum/daily-scrum/
http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/weighty-matter-daily-scrum
http://www.effectivemeetings.com/teams/teamwork/scrum.asp

Apresentei para meus colegas de equipe, e resolvemos implementar a diária durante uma fase do projeto que estamos com o prazo apertado e esta técnica realmente nos ajudou a manter o foco e conseguir entregar o software no prazo acordado.

Uma reunião diária deve durar em torno de 15 minutos, portanto não se trata daquelas reuniões prolongadas e se que se arrastam por horas. A ideia principal desta reunião não é solucionar problemas, mas sim identificar se a equipe está no caminho certo, ou caso algum membro do time esteja com problema, este poderá sinalizar para todas pessoas presentes e ‘pedir ajuda’.

As perguntas típicas a serem respondidas numa diária são as seguintes:
“O que você fez ontem?”
“O que você fará hoje?”
“Existe algum impedimento para execução da sua tarefa?”

É recomendado que os participantes fossem os mais breves o possível em suas respostas.  Caso alguém enfrente um impedimento deve sinalizar na diária para que possa ser resolvido fora dela. Típicas assertivas para sinalizar que necessita de ajuda são:

“Eu estou com problemas em debugar o problema com o programa xpto.”

“Eu estou com dificuldades em aprender determinada tecnologia e gostaria de parear com alguém.”

“O departamento VP me pediu para trabalhar em outra coisa por um dia ou dois.”

Apesar de exigir uma equipe com uma certa senioridade em desenvolvimento de softwares, quando feita da maneira correta, a reunião diária pode ajudar qualquer tipo de equipe a manter o foco e aos membros cooperarem entre si para a entrega do software com qualidade e no devido prazo.

Answer (score 2):

A "Daily Scrum" é um evento (reunião) cuja duração é, obrigatoriamente, limitada a 15 minutos. Serve para que a equipe de desenvolvimento possa sincronizar suas atividades e criar o planejamento para as próximas 24 horas.

Isso é feito inspecionando o trabalho desde a última "Daily Scrum" e gerando a previsão do trabalho que pode ser realizado até a próxima reunião.

A "Daily Scrum" é mantida no mesmo lugar e horário todos os dias para reduzir sua complexidade. Durante a reunião, cada desenvolvedor explica:

- O que eu fiz ontem que ajudou a equipe de desenvolvimento a atingir o objetivo da sprint?
- O que eu vou fazer hoje para ajudar a equipe de desenvolvimento a atingir o objetivo da sprint?
- Eu vejo algum impedimento que me atrapalha ou que atrapalha a equipe de desenvolvimento a atingir o objetivo da sprint?

Resumidamente é isso. Com informações desta reunião tanto o "Scrum Master" quanto o "Product Owner" podem ou não tomar ações.

Answer (score -2):

Cara, essa reunião, basicamente detalha quais passos cada membro do time irá realizar, quais já foram concluídas e quais dificuldades está encontrando em seu caminho, o objetivo é dar um Follow up e identificar atrasos e dificuldades na entrega do projeto, sem falar que com a cultura de colaboração o Scrum pode ajudar as pessoas se ajudarem em alguma demanda especifica desenvolvendo nova habilidades.